# Laravel application CI with Docker & Gitlab

Tags: php, laravel, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I tried to optimize a workflow for a new laravel application and i want try docker and gitlab-ci

But I'm blow my mind how manage properly.
This is how i think manage my application.

- Each commit on master build will run a dind gitlab runner.
- Will run docker-compose-test.yml for check regression
- If test success, will build a new image and push in private registry
- Run a script for getting new image of the app in production server (througth ssh but it's the same server)

But it's con :

- DockerFile of app1 is a pure application code container, bad idea. But if i want run app1 ten time i will have 10 ngxin service (1/container) ?

How did you manage this ?

[image: CI Example]

Comment: It's difficult to say what you're asking here. It seems a general question about architecture or some kind of vague thing about your application's structure. Not answerable.

Comment: Yes is more an architecture question and best practice about docker and CI with docker.